# How can I repopulate a matrix field on a front-end form?

Tags: matrix, user-profile, validation

I have a matrix field on my front-end form. Everything is working properly, data is saved correctly etc.

I am testing & trying to break things and I noticed I wasn't repopulating those fields if validation failed.

Here is how I am attempting to repopulate the value(s) in my front-end form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[myMatrixFieldHandle][new1][type]" value="blockType">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[myMatrixFieldHandle][new1][enabled]" value="1">

...
value="{{ entry.myMatrixFieldHandle.blockType.fieldHandle }}"
...
```

When I dump the above, I am getting the whole object back. I'm not sure how to get to the actual field's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example above, here is how you can re-populate the given matrix field(s). The below is assuming only one matrix field is visible by default `[0]`. Depending on your use case, you may need to dynamically generate the index number.

```
...
{%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.myMatrixFieldHandle[0].fieldHandle }}"{% endif -%}
...
```